# Can I Find Different Value with Same Formula?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code that finds the speed of an object by entering 'Distance' and 'Time'. I want to develop a code that takes either value whether it is Distance, Time or Speed, and finds the appropriate value. I don't want to write code for each value and I want it to work under one code (read note below).
Code:

```
def speed(distance, time):
    return distance/time

distance = int(input("Enter Distance Traveled(in meters): "))
time = int(input("Enter Time Taken(in sec): ")) 

print(f'Speed of Object is: {speed(distance, time)} m/s')
```

Note: This is a mockup program that I created to display a more complex situation that I am in. The formula (that I am using in my original program) is much more complex and has more than 8 values (in code above it's only 3).

Comment: This is quite unclear. There is no magic happening. You need to code a function for each of your missing values, input the other 2 and compute the third. You could use some kind of symbolic math , provide it the equation and all the given inputs and see if it can solve it for you - see f.e. https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/sympy.html

Comment: It means that I have to code for every possible case. Am I right?

Comment: Is it for Excel only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define three arguments, defaulted as `None` and pass the arguments by name. Then, according to the missing value, calculate it. Something like:

```py
def calc_missing(speed=None, distance=None, time=None):
    if speed is None:
        return f'Speed of Object is: {distance/time} m/s'
    if distance is None:
        return f'distance of Object is: {speed*time} m'
    if time is None:
        return f'time of Object is: {distance/speed} s'

print(calc_missing(speed=50, time=2))
print(calc_missing(distance=50, time=2))
print(calc_missing(speed=50, distance=100))
```

This will give:

```
distance of Object is: 100 m
Speed of Object is: 25.0 m/s
time of Object is: 2.0 s
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from the wording of your question, if I completely understand what you want.  If you are looking for a function which will compute the missing parameter in the distance equation d= v*t when given two of the three parameters, here is a solution:

```
def evaluateDistanceEquation(**kargs):
    """Evaluate the distance equation dist = velocity* time
       Given two of three parameters return tuple contaioning
       all three in form (dist, vel, time) if improper inputs
       return None"""
    rslt = [kargs.pop('distance', None), kargs.pop('velocity', None), kargs.pop('time', None)]
    if rslt[0] == None:
        if rslt[1] != None and rslt[2] != None:
            rslt[0] = rslt[1]*rslt[2]
            return tuple(rslt)
        else:
            return None
    if rslt[2] == None:
        if rslt[0] != None and rslt[1] != None:
            rslt[2] = rslt[0]/rslt[1]
            return tuple(rslt)
        else:
            return None
    if rslt[0] != None and rslt[2] != None:
        if rslt[0] != None and rslt[2] != None:
            rslt[1] = rslt[0]/rslt[2]
            return tuple(rslt)
        else:
            return None
```

Now if you execute (for example):

```
distvals = evaluateDistanceEquation(distance = 12, time= 2.4)
if distvals:
    print(f"The Result of dist evaluation is Dist= {distvals[0]}, Velocity= {distvals[1]}. Time= {distvals[2]}")
else:
    print('Error must provide two out of three parameters from distance, velocity, and time')
```

you will get back:

```
The Result of dist evaluation is Dist= 12, Velocity= 5.0. Time= 2.4
```

and if you execute:

```
distvals = evaluateDistanceEquation(velocity= 5.0)
if distvals:
    print(f"The Result of dist evaluation is Dist= {distvals[0]}, Velocity= {distvals[1]}. Time= {distvals[2]}")
else:
    print('Error must provide two out of three parameters from distance, velocity, and time')
```

The result will be:

```
Error must provide two out of three parameters from distance, velocity, and time
```